# Не работает цикл со списком в атрибуте класса

Tags: python

Наполняю список в атрибуте класса:

```
class Server:
    def __init__(self, ip):
        self.ip = ip
        self.descendants = []

    def add_descendant(self, descendant):
        self.descendants.append(descendant)

primary_server = Server("119.11.001.226")
first_descendant = Server("119.11.001.228")
second_descendant = Server("119.11.001.130")

primary_server.add_descendant(first_descendant)
primary_server.add_descendant(second_descendant)
```

Далее пытаюсь осуществить прохождение по списку `descendants`, вызывая экземпляр класса:

```
for s in primary_server:
    print s.ip
```

Получаю ошибку `TypeError: iteration over non-sequence`

Как пройти по элементам списка-атрибута, ссылаясь на весь класс?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Протокол итераций требует, чтобы у сущности метод `__iter__()` возвращал специальный
объект-итератор с реализованным методом `next()` для python2  или `__next__()` для python3.

Короткий путь представляет собой добавление в класс метода в котором возвращается внутренний итератор:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self.descendants)
```

Тогда цикл отработает.

Ну или можно сделать через `self` и написать логику самому. Добавить атрибут длина
последовательности `index`, изменять его при добавлении/удалении элементов в список
`self.index += 1` в `add_descendant`. Реализовать методы `__iter__` и `__next__`.

```
class Server:
    def __init__(self, ip):
        self.ip = ip
        self.descendants = []
        self.index = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.index == 0:
            raise StopIteration
        self.index = self.index - 1
        return self.descendants[self.index]

    def add_descendant(self, descendant):
        self.descendants.append(descendant)
        self.index += 1

primary_server = Server("119.11.001.226")
first_descendant = Server("119.11.001.228")
second_descendant = Server("119.11.001.130")

primary_server.add_descendant(first_descendant)
primary_server.add_descendant(second_descendant)

print primary_server.next().ip
print "--"
for s in primary_server:
    print s.ip

# 119.11.001.130
# --
# 119.11.001.228
```

Comment: взлетит только с next(), с __next__() не получиться